# Meteor : how to make Relationships one to many?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, relationships

I am trying to create a follower system like twitter and I want to show posts only for following users.
I'm not sure about my publish code.

I have 2 collections:

```
1- Posts {
  "_id": "3HrXtbHZ8WqHJJpyC",
  "post": " some text",
  "owner": "Wdc84ED9zt4Ssxsh4",
  "username": "MJK",
  "createdAt": "2016-01-28T11:53:33.253Z"
}

2- Follwers {
  "_id": "ShKWgeaP9BFPuQWwL",
  "follower": "MJK",
  "following": "michael"
}
```

**publish code**

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).username;
  var follower = Followers.find({followers: user}).following;
  var posts = Posts.find({username: {$in: follower}});
  return posts;
});
```

**subscribe**

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts');
```

**client code**

```
Template.content.helpers({
  'posts': function(){
    return Posts.find({}, {sort:{createdAt: -1}});
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
{{#each posts}}
<li class="collection-item avatar">
  <span class="title"><a href="/{{username}}">{{posts.username}}</a></span>
  <p>{{time}}
{{post}}
{{/each}}
```

But no posts appear in the browser.
I think my publish code is wrong. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your follower line to this:

```
var follower = Followers.find({follower: user}).fetch().map(function(follower) {
    return follower.following;
});
```

The changes I made:

1. Changed `followers: user` to `follower:user` because I don't see a followers property in your Followers collection.
2. Added the `fetch()` after your `find()` query to return an array instead of a cursor.
3. Used `.map()` to transform your array of objects into an array of username strings to feed to posts.